# What "Attributes" can Serena Mariner's SOAP API touch in UpdateInvestment()?

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to write an interface between a home-grown project management system and Serena Mariner.  (The bigwigs like to read Mariner, the worker bees like to write to the home grown system.)

How can I (programmatically?) figure out what Attribute Keys are available?

I'm actually writing the interface in PHP, but any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey. Did you ever come right with this?

Answer (score 1):

Mariner seems to [have an API](http://community.serena.com/posts/3c42b2a8fe) for working with the system. Otherwise, it might be better to ask at the [Mariner Support Forum](http://community.serena.com/hives/1eb332f6b9/summary).

Update: I took a little bit more of a look at the API and it doesn't specify the attributes, which is what your question is about. I guess the support forum is the better bet then.